# WPML taxonomies not translated

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugin-wpml

I'm using WPML for multi-language website. It works really well except for custom taxonomies.

In admin, I can only join foreign posts to foreign taxonomies (which is exactly what it should do) but on the public area, when retrieving taxonomies it seems that the current language is ignored: I get all taxonomies.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that when retrieving the taxonomy you have to do this :

```
    $args = array(
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'taxonomy' => 'projet_thematique'
    );
    $thematiques = get_terms('projet_thematique', $args);
```

The thing was done by adding the 'taxonomy' as an argument as well.

I hope it will be usefull for others ;)

Answer (score 1):

hack for filter the_terms:

```
$terms = get_terms('YOUR-TAXONOMY','hide_empty=1' );
if (!empty( $terms )){
  $term_links = "";
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  if($term->term_id == icl_object_id($term->term_id,'YOUR-TAXONOMY',false,ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE)){
    $term_links[] = '<li><a href="'.$category_url.'?YOUR-TAXONOMY='. $term->slug.'">
     ' . $term->name . '' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
  }
  }
echo join( '', $term_links );
}
```